# Laravel5.1, リレーション, EloquentORM, 多対多, ソート

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```html
<table border="true">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:100px">Table</th>
    <th colspan="3" style="width:300px">Columns</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px">Articles</td>
    <td style="width:100px">id</td>
    <td colspan="2" style="width:200px; color: #aaaaaa">その他</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px">Article_Tag</td>
    <td style="width:100px">id</td>
    <td style="width:100px">article_id</td>
    <td style="width:100px">tag_id</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px">Tags</td>
    <td style="width:100px">id</td>
    <td style="width:100px">name</td>
    <td style="width:100px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

上のTagsテーブルの[name]でArticlesテーブルをソートしたいです。
公式ドキュメントを参照して下のようにEagerLoadingとクロージャを使ってみましたがソートされません。
ArticleモデルとTagモデルは互いにbelongsToManyのみでリレーション定義されていて、外部キー制約も正しく定義されています。正常にこれらのデータは出力できますが、ソートされません。もちろんgetTag関数に引数は与えていません。(与えた場合も[name]による絞込みがされません。)

```
use App\Article;
use App\Tag;

...

public function __construct(Article $article)
{
  $this->article = $article;
}

...

public function getTag($tag = NULL)
{  
$flag = isset($tag);

$articles = $this->article->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->with([
    'tags' => function($query) use ($flag, $tag){
        ($flag)
            ? $query->where('name', $tag)
            : $query->orderBy('name');
    }
])->paginate(15);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559136/laravel5-1-relation-eloquentorm-many-to-many-sort マルチポスト

Comment: 急いでいて日本語と英語の両方で質問したかったので、マルチポストしました。

Comment: @YutaKunimaru 英語で質問していた理由はそれなんですね。勢いでモデレーターに対応してもらうように通報してしまいました。すみません。[英語版](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559136/laravel5-1-relation-eloquentorm-many-to-many-sort)